# uisearchbar to static cell of uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am facing difficulties making my new app where I need to add two search bar in two of my tableview section. Other sections are filled with other controls which I made through the Interface Builder. When I first created the uisearchbar app I had to make it with an empty table where I was loading the data which relates to the search text of the user, now I can not do that cause I already built other interfaces. How do I make the search strings viewable on a Action Sheet kind of thing so that I dont have to delete the static cell which I created.

For the reference I am posting the picture.

[image: See the image for the issue]